# Is it possible to draw in another window (Using Opencv/ffmpeg

Tags: c++, winapi, opencv, dll

I realize this question might be closed with the "not enough research". However I did spent like 2 days googling for it and didn't find a conclusive answer.

Well I have an application that spawns a window, not written in c++. This application can have a c-interface with dlls. Now I wish to use the power of OpenCV, so I started on a dll to extend. Ss passing image data from/to the application is near impossible (only capable of passing c-strings & double values directly - using the hard drive for drawing is slowing down too much for real time image manipulation).

I am looking into letting opencv draw the image data directly - onto the window. I can gain the window handle easily, so would it then be possible to let openCV draw their data "over" the other window - or better into the other window?
Is this even possible with any library (FFMPEG, or something else)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5559366/176769), it's possible, but it's far from ideal. You can [use GDI to draw on top of the other window](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/18191) ([just convert](http://howto-code-it.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/how-to-convert-iplimage-to-hbitmap.html) [IplImage to HBITMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530344/display-iplimage-mat-opencv-in-mfc-picture-box)). [Another technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3687615/176769) is to do such drawing in a *borderless* [layered window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx).

**An easier approach is**, since you own both applications, to write a function that passes an `IplImage` between them using standard C data types, after all, `IplImage` is nothing but a data type that is built from these standard types.

Here is how you will disassemble `IplImage` into 5 standard parameters:

- The size (**int, int**) of the image (width/height);
- The (**int**) bit depth of the image;
- The number (**int**) of channels;
- And the (**unsigned char***) pixels of the image;

After receiving these parameters on the other side, you may wonder: *[how do I assemble a `IplImage` from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10125322/176769)?* Call [`cvCreateImageHeader()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#createimageheader) followed by [`cvSetData()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvsetdata#cvSetData).

Comment: hmm the problem is the other application is interpreted and from testing creation of an image - even from a build in array- is slow as hell; not something you can do a hundred times a second. It is actually a multiple times as slow as using build-in-functions to read image data from a file.